# Angular passing array of objects to JSON with Angular Material multiple select list

Tags: c#, arrays, angular, .net-core, angular-material

I am using Angular and .Net Core API.
I have an input form where I need to add an array of objects in the JSON body but I can't figure out how to do this. Please see the example below.
My problem concern the 'authors' field.

properties

```
  bookId: number;
  title: string;
  authorId: number;
  isbn: string;
  publisherId: number;
  category: string;
```

addBook method (book.component.ts)

```
  addBook() {
    var val = {
      bookId: this.bookId,
      title: this.title,
      isbn: this.isbn,
      publisherId: this.publisherId,
      category: this.category,
      authors: [{ authorId: this.authorId }]  // problem here
    };
    this.service.addBook(val).subscribe(res => {
      this.refreshBookList();
    }, err => {
      console.log(val);
    });
  }
```

Multiple list with using Angular Material (book.component.html)

```
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width mr-2">
    <mat-label>Authors</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="authorId" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let authors of AuthorList" [value]="authors.authorId">
{{authors.authorName}} {{authors.authorLastName}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Right now, when I fill in a form and click the add button I am receiving an one array of authorsIds instead of authors arrays with authorId value. For better understanding, I am expecting something like this..

```
{
    "title": "Sample title,
    "isbn": "123-41-5-12311",
    "publisherId": 1,
    "category": "Err",
    "authors": [
        { "authorId": 5 },
        { "authorId": 2 },
        { "authorId": 1 }
    ]
}
```

**My question is how can I modify my addBook method to get:**

```
authors: [
     { authorId: number;}
     .
     .
     .
     { authorId: number;}
];
```

instead of

```
authors: { authorId: number;}[];
```

Please let me know if I am wrong because I am new with Angular and Angular Material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem with a huge impact @tfa.
Code below.

```
  addBook() {
    var newArray = [];
    this.authorId.forEach(function (id) {
      newArray.push({ authorId: id });
    });

    var val = {
      bookId: this.bookId,
      title: this.title,
      isbn: this.isbn,
      publisherId: this.publisherId,
      category: this.category,
      authors: newArray
    };
    this.service.addBook(val).subscribe(res => {
      this.refreshBookList();
      console.log(val);
    }, err => {
      console.log(val);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this and angular material gives back one array of Ids. You have to loop through these and format them correctly to pass back to the webapi.

this might solve it

```
addBook() {
    this.authorItems =[];    
    angular.forEach(this.authorId, function (id) {
       this.authorItems.push({ authorId: id});
    });

    var val = {
      bookId: this.bookId,
      title: this.title,
      isbn: this.isbn,
      publisherId: this.publisherId,
      category: this.category,
      authors: this.authorItems  // problem solved
    };
    this.service.addBook(val).subscribe(res => {
      this.refreshBookList();
    }, err => {
      console.log(val);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @tfa for your response but I am using Angular framework, not AngularJS so I cant use angular.forEach method in my code. Do you know a solution for that?